# .htaccess: Trying to redirect MANY subpages to most current subpage

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Okay, I am having an issue trying to figure out this problem. Using `.htaccess`, I need to redirect all my old study guide pages to the most current. The problem is that they are updated regularly, and there is 1000's of subpages. So putting them individually would be a big waste of time.

Old, but still live, pages:

```
wwww.domain.com/studyguide/2100
wwww.domain.com/studyguide/21001
```

Need to get redirected to:

```
wwww.domain.com/studyguide/21002
```

The thing is, that I want to see if there is a way to set it up where it will always redirects to the most current page.

Comment: So it's in the format of `/studyguide/\d+` where `\d+` is any digit one or more times, and you're redirecting it to the endpoint ending in `21002`? It's not clear.

Comment: So right now it would need to be redirected to `21002`. But when we do a study guide revision, the URL would change to `/21003`. Which would mean, we need to go back in .htaccess to update the redirect.

Comment: Well how would your server know, at this point, what is the most “current” version is …? Even if you said that can be determined by a criterion such as maybe the alphabetical order of file names(?) - there isn’t really a way to work based on that with mod_rewrite. You could either rewrite all those to a script, that then determines what the most current URL is, and then redirects there again; or maybe use a symlink as rewrite target, and then update that symlink to point to the newest actual file or something like that.